# CSS3 or JavaScript Slider How-Did-They-Do-That?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I am working on a new site and wanted to figure out how Apple and IBM did a slider on their website.

Examples:
http://www.ibm.com/us/en/sandbox/ver2/ and
http://www.apple.com/imac/

Notice the way the text and images slide in opposite directions. It appears they do it with CSS3, yet I can't figure out how they get the onclick of the buttons below, to work without swapping out classes.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically looking at the Apple slider there is a couple of things going on.

They are using JS to hook into the click event and when they do that, they are changing an attribute on the `<ul>`, this in-turn changes the CSS, which, using CSS3 transitions, provides the animation.

So having a look into the code:

Here is a snippet of the HTML code. You can see the `exited` and `entered` attributes. These are changes using javascript when a new section is required (via the onclick)

```
<ul class="ul-slider" page="1" style="width: 970px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 5px; " exited="previous">
    <li class="pb-macbook" exited="previous">...</li>
    <li class="pb-macbookpro" exited="previous">...</li>
    ...
</ul>
...
<ul class="ul-slider" page="3" style="width: 930px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 25px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 25px; " entered="next">
    <li class="pb-keyboard started" entered="next">...</li>
    <li class="pb-magicmouse started" entered="next">...</li>
    <li class="pb-magictrackpad started" entered="next">...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then, looking into the CSS (http://images.apple.com/global/styles/productbrowser.css), we see a number of [CSS3 transition/transforms properties and styles](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/)

a small snippet is provided, you can see how the different `entered` or `exited` attribute values effect the transforms, which in turn are animated by the transitions.

```
.productbrowser ul.exited ,
.productbrowser ul[exited] { display:none; }
.productbrowser li[exited]  ,
.productbrowser li[toenter]  { -webkit-animation-name:none; -webkit-animation-duration:0;

.productbrowser li[exited="next"] ,
.productbrowser li[toenter="next"],
.productbrowser li[enter="next"]   { -webkit-transform:translate3d( 3000px, 0, 0); }
```

They minified the JS so I can't really show you how thats working, but it's not too complex.

I hope this make sense and is helpful :)

Comment: Yes it does make sense, I had originally pasted the wrong url, I was looking for this effect: http://www.apple.com/imac/ however knowing what you showed there, I actually should be able to discern how to do the other effect with what you've shown me above.

Answer (score -2):

There are many JQuery javascripts available on internet so you can implement this type of slider using it. And ya JQuery has plenty of them.

You can also acquire this type of thing using javascript files.

You can visit [Menus & Navigation](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/index.html) of **Dynamic Drive** for more information. You can also get the source by which you can find out the thing you are searching for..

Comment: It's not the menu. And JQuery and MooTools (my preference) have similar to what I'm looking for but they all slide the elements in the same direction.

Comment: You have to take javascript since you cannot have click event on css.

Comment: He wants to know how the animations work, not how the click event works. I -1'd this answer because it didn't address the question and isn't helpful.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts: I have also provided a l;ink in which Bryan can have the core idea how the navigation or slider works.

Comment: I understand that, but he wasn't looking for a script, he was trying to understand how they worked. (Original Question) *Can anyone provide some insight?* - This means he's looking for information that will help him understand how the effect is achieved. Your link is fine *if* he was just asking for scripts, but that's not what was being asked. Also, reading scripts is not always very useful.